# Adding JLabels to JFrame using ActionListener and for loop

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, label

I want to add a JLabels to JFrame with for loop and ActionListener. The idea is: I have a button, and when i click the button, program is adding labels, but in my code when i click button nothing happens, without button and ActionListener, labels are adding properly. Code:

```
public class Test extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
JLabel[] labels;
TextField dane;
JButton button;

public Test(){
    super();
    dane=new TextField();
    button=new JButton("Oblicz");
    setLayout(new GridLayout(33,0));
    add(dane);
    add(button);
    setVisible(true);
    pack();
}
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent v) {
        showGUI();
        revalidate();
        repaint();
}
private JLabel[] createLabels(){
    JLabel[] labels=new JLabel[20];
    for (int i=0;i<20;i++){
        labels[i]=new JLabel("message"+i);
    }
    return labels;
}
private void showGUI(){
    labels=createLabels();
    for (int i=0;i<labels.length;i++){
        this.add(labels[i]);
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args){
    new Test();
}    
}
```

Ok, i changed my code as you sugested, but it still doesn't work. What's wrong here ? I have no idea( I'm very beginner so every suggestions would be nice )

Comment: This code does many things wrong.  1) It violates the EDT rule. 2) It adds components, then sets a layout. 3) It fails to call `pack()`. 4) It mixes Swing and AWT. 5) It explicitly sets a size for the GUI. 6) `showGUI()` creates and returns labels, that are then ignored. 7) `showGUI()` declares `JLabel[] labels` again, thereby shadowing the class level attribute of the same name. ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ...but in my code when i click button nothing happens

I don't see where you've attached a listener to your button. Try:

```
button.addActionListener(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

When adding components to a visible GUI the basic code is:

```
panel.add(...);
panel.revalidate(); // to invoke the layout managers
panel.repaint(); // to paint the new components
```

So after the loop is finished adding the labels to the frame you need to revalidate() the frame.